# Threejs export part of the Object3ds faces as image after teture has been added trough uv map

Tags: three.js

Threejs export part of the Object3ds faces as image after teture has been added trough uv map.

I this even possible ?

EDIT:
I want to export part of my 3d object with texture applied so that i can print that part on sheet of paper

Comment: You have to re-work your question. So far, it's very unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Added some explanation

Comment: Have you tried just printing the page? If not, what sort of export are you looking for? An image? A 3D model?

Comment: It's still unclear what you are asking? Do you mean like papercraft?

Comment: I want to export part of object to image. I cna use canvas clip and take scrn shoot but thats bad :D